# Button rendered by javascript collapsible event listener not working

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Am trying to create a note saver using firebase realtime database, the subjet of the note is collapsible (which displays the text) but after using javascript to render the content from firebase the collapsible button becomes deactivated

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
    if (user) {
        var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
        var urlRef = firebase.database().ref("/user/" + userId + "/note/");

        urlRef.once("value", function (snapshot) {
            snapshot.forEach(function (data) {
                var subject = data.val().Subject;
                var text = data.val().Note;
                var date = data.val().Date;

                content += '<button style="font-weight: 900;" type="button" class="collapsible"> ' + subject + ' <span style="float: right;">' + date + '</span></button> ';
                content += '<div class="content"> <p>' + text + '</p></div>';

            });
            $('#my_notes').append(content);


        });
    }
});
```

the code for collapsible function is this

```
 var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
    coll[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var content = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (content.style.display === "block") {
            content.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            content.style.display = "block";
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: do you attach the listeners after each update from firebase?

Comment: yes i did, but it still could not  collaps the button

Comment: Well, if you really attached the listeners after each update from firebase as @pilchard asked then you may consider generating the button and paragraph in the content you are appending, as JavaScript objects and adding the eventListener, let me post an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably creating the button and content paragraph with `document.createElement('el');` function and adding the event listener immediately could be better. ... Something like this:

```
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
      if (user) {
        var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
        var urlRef = firebase.database().ref("/user/" + userId + "/note/");

        urlRef.once("value", function (snapshot) {
          snapshot.forEach(function (data) {
            var subject = data.val().Subject;
            var text = data.val().Note;
            var date = data.val().Date;

            // create button to contain subject and date
            const button = document.createElement('button');
            button.classList.add('collapsible');
            button.style.fontWeight = 900;
            button.innerHTML = `${subject}  <span style="float: right;">${date}</span>`;

            // create paragraph to contain content and hide it
            const content = document.createElement('p');
            content.textContent = text;
            content.style.display = 'none';
            
            // add button and content to notes
            $('#my_notes').append(button);
            $('#my_notes').append(content);

            // add click event listener to button
            button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
              event.target.classList.toggle('active');
              const content = event.target.nextElementSibling;
              if (content.style.display == 'block') {
                content.style.display = 'none';
              } else {
                content.style.display = 'block';
              }
            });
         });
        });
      }
    });
```